# Dynamic value binding of JSF component

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

How do I bind a value of certain component dynamically at runtime?
For example, I have the following component tag,

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.someProp}" />
```

In my case, "#{bean.someProp}" is only known at runtime.

What's the best strategy to implement this?

Should I traverse the component tree and set the value binding programmatically? If yes, at which JSF lifecycle phase should I do the traversing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can bind it to a `Map<String, Object>` bean property where the `String` key is less or more the dynamic property name. You can access map values in EL the following way:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.map.someProp}" />
```

or

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.map['someProp']}" />
```

which can even be done a tad more dynamically where `someVar` actually resolves to a `String` value of `"someProp"`:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.map[someVar]}" />
```

You only need to ensure that the `Map` is created during bean initialization, otherwise JSF can't access the map values. EL namely won't precreate "nested properties" for you. Thus, do e.g. direct instantiation:

```
public class Bean {
    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
```

.. or inside a Constructor or `@PostConstruct` if you like.

Comment: Ok I get what you meant. This is a good idea, except that I will loose all metadata defined in the annotations in my entities. This will also mean loosing the advantage of using <s:validate/> (the hibernate validation tag from SEAM) and all other infrastructure that depends on annotation metadata. 

FYI, I'm doing this to make a framework that implements 'naked object' pattern (one ref implementation is http://www.nakedobjects.org/). Basically it inspect an entity and automatically build related tables and forms (in this case, component tree).

Comment: Urm,... on the second thought, using this approach I don't have to loose all that annotations metadata. 
I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: This is the way i do it currently. By doing this, I'm loosing the advantage of <s:validate/> and has to re-implement validation somewhere else. It's trivial though, just a matter of calling hibernateValidator.validate(bean).

Comment: Does this imply that it is impossible to do a read/write binding to a bean property (with setter/getter) with the `#{bean.map['someProp']}`? This would be surprising because it is possible to read a setter/getter property with that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is you can add a layer of abstraction to your bean.

```
public String getDynamicProp() {
   ...Code to determine and return the correct property based on the meta-data...
}

public void setDynamicProp(String input) {
   ...Code to determine and return the correct property based on the meta-data...
}
```

Then you would tie your JSF directly to the dynamic prop:

```
#{bean.dynamicProp}
```

However, this won't hang on to the metadata like validators and the like you were wanting. However, you can programatically invoke validation and handle it yourself.