# get the list of element in <ui:repeat> already checked in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have an `<ui:repeat>` in which I has a list of object , next to each of those object I need to have a `checkbox` ( to check this element). 
I want to know how could I integrate those checkboxes inside the `<ui:repeat>` in order to have many rows and each rows needs to has the `object.getName()` and next to it I need to have the `checkbox` ?

If this is feasible, Please how could I obtain those checked objects in the backing bean ?

```
 <ui:repeat var="myObject" varStatus="status"
                value="#{Bean.getListObjects}">
            <b>#{status.index+1} .</b>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{myObject.name}" />

             //need the checkbox here for example

  </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Just create a map with the object UID as the key and a boolean as the value. Then value-bind each checkbox to a map entry (`value="#{map[object.id]}"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a map with the object UID as the key and a boolean as the value. Then value-bind each checkbox to a map entry.

Assuming your names are unique, you could use them. So, in you bean create a `Map<String,Boolean>`, and initialize the map with each object.

You can use the map to in the checkbox value like `value="#{bean.map[object.name]}"`.

See also:

- [Dynamic value binding of JSF component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226122/dynamic-value-binding-of-jsf-component)

Comment: works fine thank you and thank you BalusC for the suggestion !